# Search / Replace All PHP Variable in Blade using Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

So, I am just curious if there are any simple method to select / replace all declared PHP variable in blade using Visual Studio Code. Because, I am trying to make the static version from its original version and the code itself has ~~500 line of code so it would take some times to remove / edit those variables manually. Or maybe using Regex Method ? (since I am not really expert about those regex rules).

[image]

Thanks before

Comment: Use VS Code's short key to select same occurrences and then update

Comment: Well the problem is all variables having different names

Comment: what do you want to replace with what

Comment: As described on my question, my goal is to make the static code version (for frontend purpose), so what I meant is the variable stuff should be replaced with "-" (for example), but since these variables is not occurence, I need to modify each variables manually

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Shift + F`

this is the VS Code shortcut

Comment: I assume this answer apply if we want to match all the same keyword, am I (?) But what I'm trying to achieve here is to search all different keyword inside "{{....}}" in specific file